# Problems with cors plugin installation in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, cors

I'm doing a laravel/react application and in console when I call an endpoint I see the classic cors error.
So backend side I wanna install fruitcake/laravel-cors but when I run command composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors --ignore-platform-reqs I have error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires fruitcake/laravel-cors ^3.0 -> satisfiable by fruitcake/laravel-cors[v3.0.0].
- fruitcake/laravel-cors v3.0.0 requires illumina.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an
explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Comment: If you use laravel 10 - you not need to install this package, it has builtin support for cors.

Comment: @Maxim so What I have to do to solve my error?

Comment: I did not see error and cannot answer. “Classic cors error” can be anything. You question about package - i answer to question.

Comment: It means that your problem is not about the installing the package but the pre installed cors package in laravel 10 is not correctly configured.